# "Export UV Layout" no there in the menu

Tags: uv, export

I cannot find the "Export UV Layout" option in Blender. The menu option "Export UV Layout" is simply and plainly not there. I have this problem with Blender 2.81, 2.82, 2.83, and 2.90, so it is most certainly something I am doing wrong.

I searched for the "Export UV Layout" add-on in the preferences and the add-on is not there. Can you please tell me what do you think I am doing wrong?

I am doing as follows:

1. New project.
2. Select the default cube.
3. Change into edit mode.
4. Go to the menu UV -> Unwrap
5. Change into de UV Editing screen layout.
6. Menu: Image -> New... -> Ok
7. Select all vertices of the UV map
8. UV Menu -> and fail!

[image: Example of menu option not being there.]

I tried using the "Operator Search... (F3)" option, but it doesn't find it.

[image: Menu option not being found.]

The "Export UV Layout" is not there. Can you please spot my mistake?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

Search for 'UV' rather than 'Export' in the addons:
[image]

Comment: Indeed, there it is. Thank you very much John. You absolutely solved the problem. Best regards.